# Node api requests returns array, but error when trying to use index

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I am having a problem trying to return indexed values from an array when making a get request in node. This is using a shopify module but I believe this will apply to all get requests. 
My function is:

```
ShopifyObj.Shopify.get('/admin/products.json',  function(err, data, headers){
  console.log(data.products[0]);      
});
```

the above returns:

"console.log(data.products[0]);
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

however; when I try to console.log without the index, I get an array:

```
ShopifyObj.Shopify.get('/admin/products.json',  function(err, data, headers){
  console.log(data.products);      
});

//returns
 [ { id: 6560603013,
title: 'Dog',
body_html: 'A cute dog',
vendor: 'Test store 1994 1994',
product_type: '',
created_at: '2016-10-27T11:11:32-04:00',
handle: 'dog',
updated_at: '2016-10-27T11:11:33-04:00',
published_at: '2016-10-27T11:11:00-04:00',
template_suffix: null,
published_scope: 'global',
tags: '',
variants: [ [Object] ],
options: [ [Object] ],
images: [ [Object] ],
image:
 { id: 16395126725,
   product_id: 6560603013,
   position: 1,
   created_at: '2016-10-27T11:11:33-04:00',
   updated_at: '2016-10-27T11:11:33-04:00',
   src: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1569/4167/products/imagejpeg_0_5.jpg?v=1477581093',
   variant_ids: [] } },
  { id: 6560596805,
title: 'Long sleeve tshirt',
body_html: 'Super long sleeves',
vendor: 'Test store 1994 1994',
product_type: '',
created_at: '2016-10-27T11:10:45-04:00',
handle: 'long-sleeve-tshirt',
updated_at: '2016-10-27T11:13:56-04:00',
published_at: '2016-10-27T11:10:00-04:00',
template_suffix: null,
published_scope: 'global',
tags: 'dog, short-sleeve-t-shirt',
variants: [ [Object] ],
options: [ [Object] ],
images: [ [Object] ],
image:
 { id: 16395113157,
   product_id: 6560596805,
   position: 1,
   created_at: '2016-10-27T11:10:47-04:00',
   updated_at: '2016-10-27T11:10:47-04:00',
   src: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1569/4167/products/profilepic.jpg?v=1477581047',
   variant_ids: [] } },
  { id: 6560275461,
title: 'Short Sleeve T-Shirt',
body_html: 'A nice t-shirt',
vendor: 'Test store 1994 1994',
product_type: '',
created_at: '2016-10-27T10:38:58-04:00',
handle: 'short-sleeve-t-shirt',
updated_at: '2016-10-27T10:38:59-04:00',
published_at: '2016-10-27T10:38:00-04:00',
template_suffix: null,
published_scope: 'global',
tags: '',
variants: [ [Object] ],
options: [ [Object] ],
images: [ [Object] ],
image:
 { id: 16394553413,
   product_id: 6560275461,
   position: 1,
   created_at: '2016-10-27T10:38:59-04:00',
   updated_at: '2016-10-27T10:38:59-04:00',
   src: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1569/4167/products/World-Wide-Web.jpg?v=1477579139',
   variant_ids: [] } } ]
```

I feel like I am doing something wrong in regards to async but I cannot figure it out. When a settimeout() of the console.log for a few seconds it will display properly. Is there any way to get my desired result without having to use settimeout for an arbitrary amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving, is undoubtedly a JSON string.
In order to use the data as array object you need to parse it first.

```
var data = JSON.parse(data.products);
console.log(data[0]);
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, however when i do that I get  [object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: I was gooing to add this but I didn't:
if this fails - although it shouldn't - you could try 

 `   var data = Function( "return"+data.products)();
    console.log(data[0]);`

But that's for debugging purposes only! Until you resolve the problems with the string format returned.

Comment: Sorry, I get the [object Object] error when I try to do var data = JSON.parse(data).   When I try to do JSON.parse(data.products) I get undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native) and for your function I get returnundefined
^

ReferenceError: returnundefined is not defined

Comment: Here is what I cannot understand, console.log(data.products instanceof Object) returns true, however console.log(data.products instaceof Array) returns false.

Comment: You need to send us the exact return of your `data.products`, to see if the string is a valid JSON array. And you will most probably need to make use of the API parser you are using.

Comment: In that case your API is returning an *object Object* not an *object Array* so you'll need to use object syntax instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion, I made an error up there, when I do console.log(data.products instanceof Array);
      console.log(data.products) in the terminal I get returned true and then the long array exactly how it appears in my initial question post up there. However, if I do console.log(data.products instanceof Array);
      console.log(data.products[0]) I get returned false and that it is undefined, and that my authentification failed before that.  it seems that once i add the [0] it tries to evaluate it immediately before my authentication runs.